# How can I add field to request body in django middleware

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-middleware

I want to add new field in request body in middleware and use it in views.

I googled it but the results was not worked.

How can I do it?

Django v2 python 3.6

Comment: What does the body of the incoming request contain to begin with? What sort of "field" do you want to add?

Comment: Only a simple string.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a separate custom middleware which will process the request before landing to a particular view. Below is the code for custom middleware:

```
class ProcessRequestMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    """
    This middleware appends new payload in request body
    """

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, *view_args, **view_kwargs):
        request_data = getattr(request, '_body', request.body)
        request_data = json.loads(request_data)
        # here you can write the logic to append the payload to request data
        request._body = json.dumps(request_data)
        return None
```

Note - The middleware was place inside an app common (common/middleware/custommiddleware.py)

Now add this middleware to settings.MIDDLEWARE list:

```
"common.middleware.custommiddleware.ProcessRequestMiddleware"
```

Now you can retrieve the payload, which you had appended in custommiddleware,  inside any of the views you want by just calling the `json.loads(request.body)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
class SimpleMiddleware:
def __init__(self, get_response):
    self.get_response = get_response

def __call__(self, request):
    my_request  = request.GET.copy()
    my_request['foo']='bar'
    request.GET = my_request
    response = self.get_response(request)
    return response
```

I tried this for you:  added above code into: `example.py` Then added `'example.SimpleMiddleware',` into `MIDDLEWARE`

My `view` method:

```
def index(request):
    for key in request.GET:
         print (key, '--->', request.GET[key])
    return render(request, 'example.html')
```

able to print `foo ---> bar` browser sends the request.

Comment: `def process_request(self, request):
        request.foo = 'bar'

        print(json.loads(request.body))
        return None`

I added this code but it didn't work.

Request.body didn't change.

Comment: please check my answer now, the tricky was I used `request.GET.copy()` method to handle modification in `request`

Comment: Nope. Unfortunately this isn't work too. I'm new in django and yet this is mt problem.

Comment: do you get any error? if yes - then please share that!

Comment: No, It's just don't change.

Comment: Try following:
1. Add some syntax error in your `example.SimpleMiddleware` code - see if you get error. This will confirm your code is enabled 
2. Add `print` statement at every block and see if you get at least one line printed in console because above code.